# Why does apache2 start multiple child processes for a single file download?

Tags: apache

I'm running apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The web server is dedicated to only serve mp4 video files. Having the server status module enabled, I'm watching the server spawn 3 child processes for every mp4 download request. This happens regardless of whether my app is trying to load the files or whether I'm doing it manually via wget, or via web server. None of those requests are repeated more than once. Yet the server still creates 3 children, all running as separate PIDs.

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does that for speed.

Actually, it is supposed to [pre-`fork()` on startup](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html). There are security issues that resolves too:

- Start Apache2 as root
- Open (i.e. `listen()` on) port 80 and 443 etc. (possible as root)
- `fork()`
- Drop user rights to www-data:www-data (user:group), which makes the service much more secure
- `accept()` connection(s) and process them (in the child)

By default, it creates a certain number of children. You should be able to change that number. It was 10 before. Some larger servers will create 100.

The children will then answer a certain number of requests (100 by default if I'm correct) and then exit. When they exit the parent process detects the fact that the child died and it calls `fork()` again to adjust the number of children. Further `fork()` calls happen only if the various thresholds allow it.

Comment: thank you. I understand the pre forking for speed. But having multiple processes on the server to serve a single connection doesn't make sense to me. As far as I can tell, the client side does not open multiple connections, so I don't see the benefit of opening multiple servers?

Comment: The server cannot know how many "simultaneous" connections are going to happen all at once. However, what you may be seeing, assuming the number of processes increases as you connect, is Apache2 making sure that it still has a minimum of X children ready to accept new connections.

Comment: Note that now a day browsers do make multiple connections in parallel to load several files at once.

Comment: Ok. I suspect there were leftover connections from the browser connections. wget indeed only makes one connection.